# How do I get self-sizing cells in OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, autolayout, nstableview

How do I get self-sizing cells in an `NSTableView` just like iOS 8's `UITableView`'s `rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;` and setting the cell in auto layout?

I've tried `rowHeight = NSTableViewAutomaticDimension;` but it doesn't exist. Is there such thing? I only need to support OS X 10.10 and higher.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `autoresizingMask` property of the cell view?

Comment: @boyfarrell Hmm, can I use it with autolayout?

Comment: Sure, `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=YES` on your cell view.

Comment: @boyfarrell How do I use it on a storyboard with autolayout enabled?

Comment: Can you post your project or an example project, I'll take a look.